# Unable to start Apache on Ubuntu 18.04 (huge error log)

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

So, I've uninstalled and reinstalled Apache2. However, when I try and start it, I get a very generic error message.

So I run the following: sudo journalctl | tail

And I get this mammoth response:

```
May 05 13:49:35 pop-os PackageKit[3244]: refresh-cache transaction /34221_ddbebcaa from uid 1000 finished with failed after 5329ms
May 05 13:49:35 pop-os io.elementary.a[4468]: Client.vala:681: Update_cache: Refesh cache async failed - W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
                                              E: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>)
May 05 13:49:37 pop-os PackageKit[3244]: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
May 05 13:49:37 pop-os PackageKit[3244]: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
May 05 13:49:43 pop-os PackageKit[3244]: refresh-cache transaction /34222_ebbadcdb from uid 1000 finished with failed after 5379ms
May 05 13:49:43 pop-os io.elementary.a[4468]: Client.vala:681: Update_cache: Refesh cache async failed - W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
                                              E: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>)
May 05 13:49:45 pop-os PackageKit[3244]: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
May 05 13:49:45 pop-os PackageKit[3244]: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
```

What on earth is going on here? (I am using POP OS as my distro).

Answer (score 0):

Yarn's GPG key expired. Fetch an updated key with

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Related:

- [Yarn Installation Debian / Ubuntu](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable)